# Clojure - No matching method found for select method in DataFrame when using Flambo

Tags: apache-spark, clojure, apache-spark-sql, flambo

I'm using [Flambo](https://github.com/yieldbot/flambo) to work with Spark. I want to retrieve a [DataFrame](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) which contains given column names. I wrote a simple function as follows:

```
(defn make-dataset
  ([data-path column-names and-another]
    (let [data (sql/read-csv sql-context data-path)
      cols (map #(.col data %) column-names)]
      (.select data (Column. "C0")))))
```

I get the following exception when i execute it.

> IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: select for class org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:80)

What am i doing wrong? Why `col.` works whereas `select.` doesn't when both of them are available from the same Class?
Please help me if i am wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataFrame.select` you are trying to call has following signature:

```
def select(cols: Column*): DataFrame
```

As you can see it accepts a vararg of `Column` whereas you provide it a single, bare `Column` value which doesn't match the signature, thus the exception. Scala's varargs are wrapped in `scala.collection.Seq`. You can wrap your column(s) into something that implements `Seq` using following code:

```
(scala.collection.JavaConversions/asScalaBuffer [(Column. "C0")])
```

Comment: Thanks for that. By `def select(cols: Column*): DataFrame` i understood it allows variable arguments, which i assumed it should allow a single `Column` value. Got mislead from Java's documentation. Cleared the misunderstanding. So i will take `xxx*` as a seq from here on. I did try the scala seq wrapping. It works.

Answer (score 0):

in Clojure, use Arrays to pass to varargs fields. I have the same issue was resolved when I called select function on dataframe using String and Array of String.

something like

(def cols-vec ["a","b","c])

(defn covert->spark-cols [columns] (into [] (map #(Column. %) columns)))

we gets fooled by the way the java api works when it comes to collection... 
when method signature says ... java is ok with one values where as Clojure expects a collection.